# Run time error 9: Subscript out of range for Advance Filter using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use advance filter data in my Excel workbook.

```
Sub Filter(FTO As Variant)

Dim  OB1 As Workbook, InitialName As String

With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
End With

        Set OB1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO)

            OB1.Activate
            OB1.Worksheets(10).Activate
            InitialName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

            Range("BF2").Select
            Set startCell = Range("A2")
            lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(startCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Columns("BF:BF").EntireColumn.AutoFit

            'Below code is used for reference to filter data according the Validation sheet. I've used current workbook name for InitialName
        'Below code gives subscript out of range for InitialName.

            ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
                                         Workbooks("& InitialName &").Sheets("Validation").Range("A1:B4"), Unique:= _
                                         False
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

I got an Error, this message is "Subscript Out Of Range :9" for below code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
                                         Workbooks("& InitialName &").Sheets("Validation").Range("A1:B4"), Unique:= _
                                         False
```

Please help me to solve it, thanks

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: `"& IntialName &"` looks like a funky name for a workbook.... just `InitialName` is all you need.

Comment: @BigBen ya funky name but it's not related to error I guess. The issue /error lies the same.

Comment: Yes it is...... Subscript out of range means you either don't have a workbook open with that name, or the workbook with that name doesn't have a sheet named `Validation`.

Comment: @BigBen workbook is open . Initialname fetches the acitveworkbook filename & have the sheet name "Validation" & sheet is also present in activeworkbook.

Comment: Clearly `"& InitialName &"` is *not* the same  as just `InitialName`; the first is just text, the second is actually a variable. `Debug.Print` the two to see the difference.

Comment: @BigBen: Attached screenshot for reference. "& InitialName &"and  InitialName both provides same values.

Comment: Please `Debug.Print "& InitialName &"`... they are *not* the same.

Comment: @BigBen "& InitialName &" doesn't provide value. It just represent text as it is. InitialName give Workbook name while use debug.print. But by providing "InitialName" does gives the same error in the code.

Comment: If you `Debug.Print "& InitialName &"`, the result is `& InitialName &`... which is *not* the name of your initial workbook. Why not just use `OB1` here to reference the workbook though, and completely avoid referencing the workbook by name.